# Django : How to show logged in users data from database

Tags: python, html, django, sqlite

I am working on invoice management system having in which user can add invoice data and it will save in database and whenever user logged in the data will appear on home page.but the problem if whenever any user logged in the home page showing other users data also  but i want active users data only. could you guys help me.

here is my home page,you can see i am logged in through user 1 but at home page user 2 data also appear
[image]

here is my code

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin
from django.views.generic import (
    ListView,
    DetailView,
    CreateView,
    UpdateView,
    DeleteView
)
from .models import Invoicelist

def home(request):
    context = {
        'invoices': Invoicelist.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, 'invoicedata/home.html', context)


class InvoiceListView(ListView):
    model = Invoicelist
    template_name = 'invoicedata/home.html'  # <app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html
    context_object_name = 'invoices'


class InvoiceDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Invoicelist


class InvoiceCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Invoicelist
    fields = ['issuer','invoice_number','date','amount','currency','other']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)


class InvoiceUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Invoicelist
    fields = ['issuer','invoice_number','date','amount','currency','other']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def test_func(self):
        invoice = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == invoice.author:
            return True
        return False


class InvoiceDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Invoicelist
    success_url = '/'

    def test_func(self):
        invoice = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == invoice.author:
            return True
        return False



def about(request):
    return render(request, 'invoicedata/about.html', {'title': 'About'})
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils import timezone
from django.urls import reverse

class Invoicelist(models.Model):
    issuer = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    invoice_number = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    amount = models.IntegerField()
    currency = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    other = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return (self.issuer)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('invoice-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

home.html

```
{% extends "invoicedata/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    {% for invoice in invoices %}
        <article class="media content-section">
          <div class="media-body">
            <div class="article-metadata">
              <h2><a class="article-title" href="{% url 'invoice-detail' invoice.id %}">{{ invoice.issuer }}</a></h2>
            </div>

            <p class="article-content">{{ invoice.invoice_number }}</p>
            <p class="article-content">{{ invoice.date }}</p>
            <p class="article-content">{{ invoice.amount }}</p>
            <p class="article-content">{{ invoice.currency }}</p>
            <p class="article-content">{{ invoice.other }}</p>
            <div class="article-metadata">
              <small class="text-muted">{{ invoice.author }}</small>
            </div>

          </div>
        </article>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

invoicelist_deatil.html

```
{% extends "invoicedata/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
  <article class="media content-section">
    <img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{ object.author.profile.image.url }}">
    <div class="media-body">
      <div class="article-metadata">
        <a class="mr-2" href="#">{{ object.author }}</a>
        <small class="text-muted">{{ object.date }}</small>
        {% if object.author == user %}
          <div>
            <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" href="{% url 'invoice-update' object.id %}">Update</a>
            <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" href="{% url 'invoice-delete' object.id %}">Delete</a>
          </div>
        {% endif %}
      </div>
      <h2 class="article-issuer">{{ object.issuer }}</h2>
      <p class="article-invoice_number">{{ object.invoice_number }}</p>
      <p class="article-date">{{ object.date }}</p>
      <p class="article-amount">{{ object.amount }}</p>
      <p class="article-currency">{{ object.currency }}</p>
      <p class="article-other">{{ object.other }}</p>
    </div>
  </article>
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to override `get_queryset()` on e.g. the list view to only include the desired user's invoices. (You'll want to do this on the update view too, to avoid users being able to edit each others' invoices.)

As an aside, your model should be called `Invoice`, unless a single instance of the model actually represents a list of invoices.

```
class InvoiceListView(ListView):
    model = Invoicelist
    template_name = 'invoicedata/home.html'
    context_object_name = 'invoices'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.model.objects.all().filter(issuer=self.request.user)
```

Comment: Hey AKX thank you for quick response, actually update view works fine but getting problem at list views and your suggested solution not working, i tried and now it is not showing anything. btw i have added update page you can check it out

Comment: Your Create view sets `author`; in that case, you'll want to filter `(author=self.request.user)`, naturally.

Comment: hey man thank you its working but when i logout from all users the home page giving me error " TypeError at /
'AnonymousUser' object is not iterable "

Comment: ‘AnonymousUser’ is the default user that the request uses when a user is not logged in. You should add a `if request.user.is_authenticated` clause in your `get_queryset()`, and if the user is not logged in, just return an empty list `[]`

Comment: @alexjerez preferably just `self.model.objects.none()` in that case so it's a queryset too.